# Can you define a global click event handler in .NET (Silverlight and ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, event-handling

As a followup to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567211/how-to-log-control-hierarchy-in-net), is there any global way to capture all click events in either Silverlight or ASP.NET?

I am basically asking if there is some way to attach a global click event handler so that I can run some code on every click event captured against all controls that handle click events, wihtout having to add the event handlers manually to each control.

If you can, I'm wondering how this can be accomplished without having to explicitly add an event handler to every control manually. One thought I had was from a top ASP.NET page or Silverlight app to traverse the entire Control tree looking for ButtonBase controls (or the equivalent in ASP.NET) and add a new event handler for the click event. However, I don't love the idea of traversing the entire tree and doing it this way. I guess in Silverlight it wouldn't be so bad as it would only have to be done when the app is loaded, but with ASP.NET I would imagine it would happen on every PostBack?

It looks something like System.Windows.EventManager.RegisterClassHandler() would do it, but I don't believe I have access to that in Silverlight, or any equivalent in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight you can attach a mouseClick event handler to the UI tree RootElement. You do not need to traverse the tree, the mouseclick event bubble up the whole tree - even if they are handled by intermediate nodes. If you want to catch also events that are already handled, you have to specify this when attaching the handler (see the bool param in my code below).

```
...
var root = System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual;
MouseButtonEventHandler handler = HandleRootMouseLeftButtonDown;
root.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, handler, true);
...
private void HandleRootMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // do some magic...
}
```